# Graph Traversal Problem

Tags: c++, pointers, graph, dijkstra, adjacency-matrix

My Dijkstra Algorithm works fine to find a path. Now I want to go back to show the way I went. I mark a visited vertex and give it a pointer to the vertex I came from "prev". Unfortunately these pointers get manipulated in some way when looping in the while loop, so that the vertices at the end don't know where they came from. Can you help me?

Probably it's a pointer problem I don't get. I have a copy constructor and a =operator.

```
int MyMatrix::searchBreadth(MyVertex &from,MyVertex &to,int mode)  
{  
queue<MyVertex> q;//queue  
vector<MyVertex> nb;//vector of neighbours  
path=INFINITY;//path is very long  
visits.push_back(from.getName());  
from.setDistance(0);  
MyVertex n("start");  
from.setPrev(n);  
q.push(from);  
while(!q.empty())  
     {  
         MyVertex v=q.front(); 

         q.pop();
         int k=v.getDistance();
         nb.clear();
         nb = getNeighbours(v);


         for(unsigned int i=0;i<nb.size();i++)
         {
             if((!nb[i].getPrev())&&path==INFINITY) nb[i].setPrev(v);

             if(!mode){//unweighted
                if(!wasVisited(nb[i].getName())){
                    nb[i].setDistance(k+1);
                    q.push(nb[i]);
                }
             }
             if(mode){//length or weight
                 if(!wasVisited(nb[i].getName())){
                     int cost=0;
                     MyEdge e = m->getEdge(v,nb[i]);
                     if(mode==1)cost=(int) e.getLength();//length
                     if(mode==2)cost=(int) e.getWeight();//weigth
                     nb[i].setDistance(k+cost);
                     q.push(nb[i]);
                 }
             }

             if((nb[i].getName().compare(to.getName())==0) && (!wasVisited(nb[i].getName()))){//path found
                int j=nb[i].getDistance();
                if(j<path)path=j;
             }
             visits.push_back(nb[i].getName());
         }//end of for
         //end of 0size if
     }//end of while
     return path;
}

MyVertex::MyVertex()
{  
name="null";  
dist=0;  
visited=false;  
prev=0;  
}              
MyVertex::MyVertex(string name)
{
this->name=name;
visited=false;
dist=numeric_limits<int>::max();
prev=0;
}

MyVertex::~MyVertex(void)
{
if (!prev) prev=0;
}

MyVertex::MyVertex(const MyVertex& V){
this->name = V.name;
this->visited=V.visited;
    this->dist=V.dist;
this->prev=V.prev;

}

MyVertex& MyVertex::operator=(const MyVertex& L){
if (this == &L){ return *this;
  }else{

    delete prev;
    dist=L.dist;
    name=L.name;
    visited=L.visited;
    prev=L.prev;

  }

  return *this; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're leaving a lot of code out, but you seem to be adjusting the `Distance` of a node -- and setting its `prev` -- without first checking whether it already has a lesser `Distance`. And once you've found *any* path, you stop setting `prev`, so that if you later find a shorter path, its nodes may not be marked.

Comment: No, its not the problem of the distance.I want to go back from the target vertex of the path to describe the way I went. So I ask the Vertex "to" for its "prev" Vertex, and this one too until,(in a loop or recursively) I find the "start" Vertex. But this pointer which is set traversing the graph gets manipulated in some way, so that in the end it doesn't point to its predecessor, instead to some other memory. :-(

Comment: @Der Graph: I don't think you understand. It's hard to be sure, since you have not posted enough code to reproduce the problem, but it looks as if the pointer is not being manipulated, it is not being set correctly.

Comment: I added the constructors. I think the problem is, my MyVertex object holds a recursive Definition of a MyVertex pointer. It is set to 0 initially and when traversing the graph each visited vertex gets its predecessor as prev set. But this only works within the first while (!q.empty()), then in some way something gets cleaned up internally and the addresses of the prev pointers aren't anymore correct.

Comment: @Der Graph: Do you think that at some time in the execution, all pointers are correct? If so, *why do you think that?*

Comment: Because I'm debugging and check the state ?! But now I actually changed the Vertex class to hold a List object of previous vertices...now it seems to work out(didn't had the time to complete it yet)...but I'm actually quite disappointed I didn't got it to work with these recursive pointers....